# List newest products on top, when sorting by attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting

I'm sorting my products by an attribute which tells if the products are "regular catalog products" or "order selection". In this way all the regular displays first, then all the ones from the order selection.
However; the products displays "old to new" within these two sections.

Is it possible to force the products to display "new to old" within these two attribute values instead?

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.2.4

UPDATE 15/11-16: The solution from @arunendra in this post ([Newly added products not showing as first in category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117855/newly-added-products-not-showing-as-first-in-category)) partly solves this, however it only work when product listings is one page. When multiple pages in prodict listing, the attribute I sort by is randomly.

Answer (score 1):

http://inchoo.net/magento/changing-default-category-sort-order-in-magento/

You can visit the above links and find complete explanation of how to achieve what you are looking for

You will have to create a new attribute and with your required name.

**In the Front end Section**

Used for Sorting in Product Listing should be true

**After that Go to your Category > Display Settings**

Select your created attribute

Comment: This solution will not achieve my goal: it requires me to edit the "best value" fields every time new products are added which is a manual time consuming job. It will also replace the attribute I'm already sorting by.